# why a Windows driver can be loaded in Virtual memory more than once?

Tags: windows, kernel

I want to know more about why Windows kernel drivers may be loaded in virtual memory more than once?
This is because I can see a driver in multiple offsets of a memory dump by Volatilty tool.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? Why is this unexpected? What ***specifically*** do you want to know?

Comment: @CodyGray That shouldn't normally happen since kernel memory space is shared among all the modules in it, there are no distinct processes like in user space.

Comment: as Icepack also said this is not expected as they all are loaded into virtual memory space of System process. so why this process need to load a driver more than once?now I have a dump of an ordinary XP SP3 and I have around 10 drivers which are loaded multiple times.

Comment: IIRC, drivers can include data segments, so if the same .sys file is loaded more than once it would be improper for Windows to reuse the existing instance.  (Also I think Windows identifies drivers by their base address, so if two drivers are using the same code the code would have to be loaded twice.)  I'm not sure why the same .sys file would be loaded more than once; perhaps it is referenced by more than one driver entry (in `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`)?